# How to draw a Silicium Lattice with TikZ (was: How to produce this image in LaTex)

Tags: tikz-pgf, line

Does anyone know how to code this in LaTex? I'm trying to learn the program I know I need to use the Tikz. If anyone knows how to make this, please do share your input. Thanks for any help! [image]

Comment: To get started with Ti*k*Z, check out Cremer's [A very minimal introduction to Ti*k*Z](https://cremeronline.com/LaTeX/minimaltikz.pdf). The [PGF and Ti*k*Z examples gallery](https://texample.net/tikz/examples) is also useful, if sometimes overwhelming.

Comment: Can you give more background info, for example which type dose that diagram belong to? Also you can attach links to or images of similar drawn diagrams.

Comment: Something like this? [code](https://git.henrimenke.com/experimentalphysik-6.git/tree/content/2014-10-30.tex#n86), [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3NYNR.png)

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Questions about how to draw specific graphics that just post an image of the desired result are really not reasonable questions to ask on the site. Please post a minimal compilable document showing that you've tried to produce the image and then people will be happy to help you with any specific problems you may have.  See [minimal working example (MWE)](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) for what needs to go into such a document.

Comment: close voters, please since this question has an answer, leave it open.

Answer (score 4):

You could use a TikZ-matrix. Then something like that:

[image]

```
\documentclass[margin=5mm, tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds} 

\begin{document}
\pgfmathsetlengthmacro\eradius{0.65ex}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
si/.style={circle, draw, fill=white},
]
\matrix (m) [matrix of nodes, nodes in empty cells,
nodes={inner sep=1ex, anchor=center},
column sep=2em, row sep=2em, 
]{
    &               &       &               &       &               &            \\
    & |[si]|Si   &       &  |[si]|Si   &       &  |[si]|Si  &            \\
    &               &       &               &       &               &            \\
    & |[si]|Si   &       &  |[si]|Si   &       &  |[si]|Si  &            \\
    &               &       &               &       &               &            \\
%1  &  2           &  3   &  4            &  5    &  6          &  7         \\
};

% Annotations
\foreach \y in {1,3,5}{
\foreach \x in {2,4,6}{
\fill[] ([yshift=0.2*\eradius]m-\y-\x.north) circle[radius=\eradius];
\fill[] ([yshift=-0.2*\eradius]m-\y-\x.south) circle[radius=\eradius];
}}

\foreach \y in {2,4}{
\foreach \x in {1,3,5,7}{
\fill[] ([xshift=0.2*\eradius]m-\y-\x.east) circle[radius=\eradius];
\fill[] ([xshift=-0.2*\eradius]m-\y-\x.west) circle[radius=\eradius];
}}

\begin{scope}[on background layer]
\foreach \y in {2,4}{
\draw[transform canvas={yshift=1ex}, 
shorten >=-1.5ex, shorten <=-1.5ex
] (m-\y-1.north west) -- (m-\y-7.north east); 
\draw[transform canvas={yshift=-1ex}, 
shorten >=-1.5ex, shorten <=-1.5ex
] (m-\y-1.south west) -- (m-\y-7.south east); 
}
\foreach \x in {2,4,6}{
\draw[transform canvas={xshift=-0.7ex}, 
shorten >=-1.5ex, shorten <=-1.5ex
] (m-1-\x.north west) -- (m-5-\x.south west); 
\draw[transform canvas={xshift=0.7ex}, 
shorten >=-1.5ex, shorten <=-1.5ex
] (m-1-\x.north east) -- (m-5-\x.south east); 
}
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Great!!!!! Now there is my positive vote for you.